# Making a glyph aligned to the right in a Panel heading in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Panel with bootstrap and I want to add a glyph in the heading but I want it to be aligned to the right. I added "text-right" to the `span` tag but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
div class="panel-group" id="the_items">
                         <div class="panel panel-default">
                             <div class="panel-heading" >
                                 <h4>The Item <span class="text-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil clickable_space" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#the_items" data-target="#n_1"></span></h4>

                             </div>

                             <div id="n_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                 <div class="panel-body">
                                     The body
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>


                 </div>
```

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `pull-right` instead of `text-right`:

```
<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil clickable_space" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#the_items" data-target="#n_1">
```

Actually `text-right` is also working, but since the width of the span fits it's element, it doesn't really matter if you align the text right, left or center. `pull-right` aligns the element to the right of it's parent.

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. But how to put two glyphs to the right next to each other? I put another span next to this glyph but they are so stick together.